# How to read number of characters, lines and words in Python

Tags: python, lines, words

```
from string import lowercase
from itertools import groupby

lines = [line.strip() for line in open('diamond.txt')] 
count=0
sumofwords=0
letters=[]

def numberoflines(lines):
       return len(lines)

def numberofletters(letters):
       count=0
       for l in letters:
             for ll in l:
               count=count+len(ll)
       return count

for s in lines:
      count=count+1
      counts = [(len(list(cpart))) for c,cpart in groupby(s) if c == ' ']    
      sumofwords=sumofwords+len(counts)+1
      letters.append(s.split())

print "Number of lines in document ",numberoflines(lines),"\n"    
print "Number of words in document ",sumofwords,"\n"
print "Number of letters in document ",numberofletters(letters)
```

This is the code, I need to print lines, characters and words in the text from diamond.txt.

The text contains this.

```
Diamond has remarkable
optical characteristics.
Because of its extremely
rigid lattice, it can be
contaminated by very few
types of impurities,
such as boron and
nitrogen. Combined with
wide transparency, this
results in the clear,
colorless appearance of
most natural diamonds.
```

The lines and words are giving correct output, but number of letters in document coming as 238.

The correct output should be 279.

Comment: how are you thinking it should be 279?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Counting each characters gives 279 !

Comment: @SteveJessop can you provide the modified code?

Comment: Just so you know, it is discouraged to ask for questions to be treated urgently here - all questions are treated as equal here, and asking for special attention may earn downvotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you're mixing things up the number of letters without whitespaces is in fact 238, while the answer you expect is the length of the whole text including whitespace which is 279 and by the way i'll prefer you use str.replace() to remove the whitespace in the text

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution

```
lines = [line for line in open('diamond.txt')]
wordscnt = 0
lettercnt = 0
for s in lines:
    wordscnt+=len(s.split())
    lettercnt+=len(s)
print "Number of lines in document ",len(lines),"\n"
print "Number of words in document ",wordscnt,"\n"
print "Number of letters in document ",lettercnt
```

or shorter solution

```
lines = [line for line in open('diamond.txt')]
wordscnt = sum( len(l.split()) for l in lines)
lettercnt = sum( len(l) for l in lines)
print "Number of lines in document ",len(lines),"\n"
print "Number of words in document ",wordscnt,"\n"
print "Number of letters in document ",lettercnt
```

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham This is typical Pythonic way.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham And I thought typical Pythonic way was proposed long before you.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham How long has the use of 'sum' was your personal solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are counting letters after splitting your lines, with means you don't count the spaces.
You could simply try len(text) for the number of letters.